# Why is Zone Index Disabled for Some Web-Parts?

Tags: web-part, web-part-zone

Salve!  In my Sharepoint Server 2010 site, I have subsite with some webparts on it.  There is only one web-part zone, and the page is a wiki page.  However, I want web-part #1 to appear below web-part #2.  Normally, one would do this by changing the "Web-part zone".  However, my property fields are grayed out in edit mode, but I also see that "AllowZoneChange" is marked to true.

How can I enable the zone-index field?  What caused the field to be disabled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is disabled on Wiki pages, because its not really a web part zone, but a rich-text editor. However you can move the web parts by using Drag&Drop.

Comment: That is the answer!  I don't suppose that can be done with Powershell...

Answer (score 1):

This doesnt happen with all web parts on this page? I was thinking that maybe the web part zone was configured to disallow moving the web part. Is there only one web part zone on the page? If there is only one web part zone then the options would be grayed out to change the zone, but should show for positioning. What type of page is it? (Wiki, page layout, blank web part zone)

Comment: Hi, Cory.  I have three web-parts.  Yes, there is only one zone.  The page is a wiki page - the default home page of a blank site (if I remember correctly, it's been awhile).  If it is the zone that is configured so, how do I change the setting?

Comment: Oh - yes, it happens with every web-part.

Comment: You would have to open the page in SharePoint Designer. OOTB though you shouldnt need to worry about this. Once open in SharePoint Designer you would right click on the zone to get the options. One of those should be around what is allowed within the webpart zone. Depending on how the farm is configured though you may not be able to open the site.

Comment: I checked all three web-parts in the zone, and they all are enabled for both edit and zone change.  I don't see anything anywhere else besides that for configuring another edit mode.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing a similar issue where the Zone index was grayed out due to the fact that all webparts were in the same Zone. Changing the Text Layout didn't for me. To resolve the issue I remove all webparts and added each webpart again. First, I highlighted the webpart that I wanted to insert my new webpart under, selected insert - webpart and my new webpart appeared directly where I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Zone Index affects the order of web parts that are in the same Zone in a web part page, but in a wiki page, this parameter is not applicable because web parts are "inline" with the wikitext in each zone - an index alone would not be sufficient to indicate the proper positioning for the renderer.

But, since it's a wiki page, you can switch to a different Text Layout using the command in the Format Text ribbon, which will create additional text zones. If you choose a layout with a header and/or footer, that might give you a way to move one web part to a lower zone with powershell.

See also [How to change the Wiki Page Layout in SharePoint 2010 using Powershell?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84153/how-to-change-the-wiki-page-layout-in-sharepoint-2010-using-powershell)